# How to access json file via chrome

Tags: jquery, json, google-chrome

I have a local json file in my web directory and want to access it.
I currently use $.getJSON() from jquery and it works fine with all browsers but chrome.

How can I access this file via chrome?

Code:

```
<script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $.getJSON('JsonData.json', function (data) {
                //using data for stuff..
            });
        })

</script>
```

Edit: totaly forgot to paste the chrome console error here:

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at
>   'file:///C:/Users/Sirzento/Desktop/website/JsonData.json' from origin
>   'null' has been blocked by CORS policy: Cross origin requests are only
>   supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension,
>   https.

Comment: Can you show us your code and the URL of your application?  I'm going on a hunch and suspecting it's an HTTPS or CORS issue.

Comment: I added the code. the site is using http. The url is just index.html. I open it local.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to boot a webserver and serve content on a local port like 3000, and then access your site through `localhost:3000`. Chrome is refusing to allow you to make AJAX requests to `file://` URLs, which is a security risk.

Comment: Does that mean if I want to access the site via internet that I must provide the port 3000 in the url? like 'DomainName:3000' ?

Comment: No, when you publish the site to the Internet your Internet-facing webserver would be listening on port 80, and you would just use `http://DomainName`.

Comment: But will this still work then if I access it via port 80 over the internet?

Comment: I'm not really sure what you're asking here. Will *what* work, making XHR or fetch requests to port 80? Yes.